# Download report from POST Request with Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, post, python-requests

I am trying to download a CSV file generated from a report at [This](https://lee.county-taxes.com/public/reports/real_estate) website.

Below is the request I am trying to replicate.

[Example of API i am trying to call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJEmj.gif)

I copy the cURL and parse it and get the following format for the request:

```
import requests

cookies = {
'_ga': 'GA1.2.938840467.1566745600',
'terminal': '174224916994986694513353793024390053397',
'__utmc': '1',
'request_timing~11947199': '2~2237~74~91~2402',
'_gid': 'GA1.2.89702438.1657551717',
'cf_clearance': 'RDmwUSB_b6JmRSJpvrM76reZifV_m6cHjCJ0kmUkAS8-1657566551-0-250',
'GSG_SESSION_ID': '322919708739472562779456661040511933493',
'is_session_valid': '1',
'plack_session': '27e03cd7d13a440955626dbc574adef85a619f88',
'__utma': '1.938840467.1566745600.1657299681.1657567143.4',
'__utmz': '1.1657567143.4.4.utmcsr=leetc.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/',
'__utmt': '1',
'session_id': '53da3a29-e3d5-4dd4-96c3-7562a0fb7715',
'_gat': '1',
'request_id~1513632513': '6441F026-014E-11ED-9669-AEADB5E8FA7B',
'__utmb': '1.5.9.1657567169673',
'request_timing~1513632513': '1~4217~79~105~4401',
 }

 headers = {
'authority': 'lee.county-taxes.com',
'accept': 'application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
# Requests sorts cookies= alphabetically
# 'cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.938840467.1566745600; terminal=174224916994986694513353793024390053397; __utmc=1; request_timing~11947199=2~2237~74~91~2402; _gid=GA1.2.89702438.1657551717; cf_clearance=RDmwUSB_b6JmRSJpvrM76reZifV_m6cHjCJ0kmUkAS8-1657566551-0-250; GSG_SESSION_ID=322919708739472562779456661040511933493; is_session_valid=1; plack_session=27e03cd7d13a440955626dbc574adef85a619f88; __utma=1.938840467.1566745600.1657299681.1657567143.4; __utmz=1.1657567143.4.4.utmcsr=leetc.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/; __utmt=1; session_id=53da3a29-e3d5-4dd4-96c3-7562a0fb7715; _gat=1; request_id~1513632513=6441F026-014E-11ED-9669-AEADB5E8FA7B; __utmb=1.5.9.1657567169673; request_timing~1513632513=1~4217~79~105~4401',
'origin': 'https://lee.county-taxes.com',
'referer': 'https://lee.county-taxes.com/public/reports/real_estate',
'sec-ch-ua': '".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

data = 'base_url=public%2Freports%2Freal_estate&parent_request_id=5955C82C-014E-11ED-A791-8C0D896639A2&report_search=cert_status%09%2F%7C%2F%09tax_year%09%3E2014%09roll_year%09*%09cert_sale_date%09%2F%7C%2F%09exemption%09%2F%7C%2F%09deed_status%09%2F%7C%2F%09standard_flag%09%2F%7C%2F%09&report_search_current_user_inputs=&session_id=322919708739472562779456661040511933493&app_url=%2Ftcb%2Fapp&page_url=public%2Freports%2Freal_estate&report_name=Certificate+Information+by+Year&selected_report=624&filetype=csv&delimiter=comma&quoting=on&pdf_report_title=Certificate+Information+by+Year+Report+(Certificate+Search)&add_run_by_to_header=on&paper_size=letter&page_orientation=portrait&page_break=auto&break_selector=tax_year&shade_alternate_rows=on&pdf_report_description=&report_download_email_address=&report_took_too_long_download_email=&displayed_columns=certificate_number%7Ccert_status%7Ctax_year%7Croll_year%7Caccount_number%7Csitus_address%7Ccert_sale_date%7Cissued_date%7Cpurchased_date%7Ccertificate_rate%7Cinterest_start_date%7Cface_amount%7Credeemed_date%7Credemption_amount_paid%7Ctransferred_date%7Cexemption%7Cdeed_status%7Cbidder_number%7Ccertificate_buyer%7Cstandard_flag&hide_results=&sort_by_displayed=&hide_public=&display_name=&current_view=certs&current_display=data&select_view=certs&last_sort_col=1&sbgb_boundary=2&search_order_column1=tax_year&search_order_column2=&select_display=data&search_order_direction1=desc&report_search_dummy=&report_search_dummy=%2F%7C%2F&report_search_dummy=%3E2014&report_search_dummy=&report_search_dummy=&report_search_dummy=%2F%7C%2F&report_search_dummy=&report_search_dummy=&report_search_dummy=&report_search_dummy=&report_search_dummy=&report_search_dummy=&report_search_dummy=&report_search_dummy=&report_search_dummy=%2F%7C%2F&report_search_dummy=%2F%7C%2F&report_search_dummy=&report_search_dummy=&report_search_dummy=%2F%7C%2F&rows_per_page=50&go_to_report_page=&report_page=1&backend=warehouse&print_cover_page=0&download_now=browser&ajax_request=0.4428397794570913&cookie_id=2025887579'

response = requests.post('https://lee.county-taxes.com/tcb/app/public/reports/real_estate/download', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Unfortunately when I run this code I get the following output in response.content:

```
b'<ajax-response><response type=\'element_errors\'></response>      <response type="element" id="message_container" class=""> </response>  <response type="element" id="report_download_util"><![CDATA[  ]]></response>  <response type="javascript"><![CDATA[\n    file_download(d_location() + \'/download_pending_report?pending_report_file=pwHy_qVA5b\');  ]]></response>\n</ajax-response>'
```

I'm not sure what to make of this? is trying to download the CSV from an API call possible? Am I using the wrong call?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
from httpx import Client
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = {
    'base_url':'public/reports/real_estate',
    'parent_request_id':'4C4ACC20-0155-11ED-9D24-CAB03D8B3709',
    'session_id':296334053076598741934874852698924119209,
    'app_url':'/tcb/app',
    'page_url':'public/reports/real_estate',
    'report_name':'Active Certificate Vendors',
    'selected_report':623,
    'filetype':'csv',
    'delimiter':'comma',
    'quoting':'on',
    'pdf_report_title':'Active Certificate Vendors Report (Certificate Sale Bidders)',
    'add_run_by_to_header':'on',
    'paper_size':'letter',
    'page_orientation':'portrait',
    'page_break':'auto',
    'break_selector':'bidder_number',
    'shade_alternate_rows':'on',
    'displayed_columns':'vendor_number|bidder_name|full_name|bidder_number|address_lines|business_telephone|email',
    'current_view':'cert_sale_bidders',
    'current_display':'data',
    'select_view':'cert_sale_bidders',
    'last_sort_col':1,
    'sbgb_boundary':2,
    'search_order_column1':'bidder_number',
    'select_display':'data',
    'search_order_direction1':'asc',
    'rows_per_page':50,
    'report_page':1,
    'backend':'mysql',
    'print_cover_page':0,
    'reset_report_name':0,
    'preserve_messages':0,
    'preserve_backend':0,
    'preserve_collapse':0,
    'ajax_request':0.6517064905478597,
    'cookie_id':1982672363
}
with Client(headers=headers, timeout=60.0, follow_redirects=True) as client:
    r = client.post('https://lee.county-taxes.com/tcb/app/public/reports/real_estate/report_results',  data=data)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    profit = soup.select_one('#report_results__results')
    print(profit.text)
```

This returns:

```
Lee County                                

                                    Lee County                                

                                    1                                

                                    c/o County LandsPO Box 398                                



                                    countyrevenuetransmittals@leeclerk.org                                 


                                    Venus 1 LLC                                

                                    Venus 1 LLC                                

                                    70                                

                                    P O Box 25177                                

                                    305-913-3333                                

                                    Hgoldenberg@g-g-h.com                                 
.....
```